# Every compact self-adjoint (linear) operator is injective (FALSE)

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

My purpose is to provide a proof, without using the spectral theorem.

---

Let $T: \scr H \to H$ be a linear compact self-adjoint operator.

$T$ self-adjoint implies:

1. $ \langle \phi, T \psi \rangle = \langle T\phi, \psi \rangle = \overline{\langle \phi, T \psi \rangle}$, which implies $\langle \phi, T \psi \rangle \in \mathbb R$.
2. $- \| \phi\| \|T\| \|\psi\| \le \langle \phi, T \psi \rangle \le \| \phi\| \|T\| \|\psi\|$

If in addition $T$ is compact, then its point spectrum $\sigma_p(T)\equiv \{ \lambda \in \mathbb C \ |\ T\psi = \lambda \psi$, $ \ $ for some $\lambda$-eigenvector $\psi \in \scr H$$\}$ is real, non-void.

In particular $\exists\ \Lambda \in \sigma_p(T)$ that verifies $|\Lambda| = \|T\| = \underset {\sigma_p(T)}{\max}|\lambda|$. Let's call the corresponding non-null $\Lambda$-eigenvector $\psi_\Lambda$.

**remark**. 1. and 2. hold $\forall\ \phi, \psi \in \scr H$. If we take $\phi \in \ker(T)$ and $\psi = \psi_\Lambda$:

$- \| \phi\| \|T\| \|\psi_\Lambda\| \le \langle \phi, T \psi_\Lambda \rangle = \langle T\phi, \psi_\Lambda \rangle = 0
$

Since $\|T\|$ and $\|\psi_\Lambda\|$ are not zero, the only possibility left is $\|\phi\| =0 \implies\phi ={\bf 0} \implies \ker(T) \equiv \{\bf 0\} $.

$T$ is hence injective. CVD(?)

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: This is not true. The $0$ operator or any self-adjoint finite rank operator satisfies the prompt but not the conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last step is wrong : since $\|\phi\|,\|T\|$ and $\|\psi_\Lambda\|$ are positive, the inequation :
$$-\|\phi\|\|T\|\|\psi_\Lambda\| \leq 0$$
is a triviality.

The result itself is wrong : a finite rank orthogonal projector is compact, bounded and self-adjoint, but is not injective.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the minus sign. Thanks.

Comment: But then... what about the spectral theorem? "For every compact self-adjoint operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$, there exists an orthonormal basis of $H$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$. More specifically, the orthogonal complement of $\ker T$ admits either a finite orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $T$, or a countably infinite orthonormal basis $ \{ \psi_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of eigenvectors of $T$, with corresponding eigenvalues $ \{ \lambda_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \mathbb R$, such that $\lambda_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$"

Comment: For an orthonormal basis to be such, ${\rm span}\{ \psi_n \} = \{ \ker T\}^\perp$ has to be dense in $H$. That means $\ker T$ has to be trivial

Comment: The results states that $(\ker T)^\perp$ admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. This gives no information on $\ker T$.

Comment: Isn't it the same orthonormal basis of $H$?

Comment: No, it's an orthonormal basis of the subspace

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot.